# Xcode, update project file automatically

Tags: xcode, ipad

I have many projects that use a bunch of exact same class.

Is there a way to add a script to Xcode, so, each time i compile, he go to a network folder and update is files from there... If newer. (i do this step manually, but could be great to automate it)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "run script" build phase to copy over files before compiling if that's really what you want to do. That would catch updates for you but I don't think it would help you if new files are added (though copying them into a location your project has a folder reference rather than a group pointing to might work).

That said I think there's a better solution. It sounds like you're reinventing a process for managing project dependencies when you could use existing tools. I would publish those shared classes as a library and add it to each project using CocoaPods and a reference to the library's git repository. That way you just need to run a `pod install` to get the latest version of your library. A good dependency manager gives you a clear understanding of which version of your dependencies you're currently using, control over when to update them, handles installing dependencies of your dependencies, and will avoid link errors from multiple static libraries attempting to each include a copy of the same common dependency.